# .htaccess replace part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Anyone here knows how to do this on .htaccess? I need to replace the part of URL that is inside the "[]".

Here is the URL: **[http://example.com/site/second/files/]**2012/08/Image.jpg

with this new URL: **[http://example-two.com/media1/]**2012/08/Image.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule ^site/second/files/(.*)$ http://example-two.com/media1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /site/second/files http://example-two.com/media1/
```